# Bash - Zenity list to display fields from two arrays

Tags: bash, zenity

I wanted to make a zenity list that takes the fields for one column from one list and the fields for the other column from another list

```
menu=("option1" "option2" "option3")
desc=("description1" "description2" "description3")
ans=`zenity --list --column=Menu "${menu[@]}" --column=Description "${desc[@]}" --height 170`
```

That didn't work because it first displays all values from the first list and then from the other:

| Menu | Description |
| --- | --- |
| option1 | option2 |
| option3 | description1 |
| description2 | description3 |

So I figured I probably need to merge them in alternating order but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man zenity` :

> ```
>   --column=STRING
>          Set the column header
> ```

So the `--column` option will only set the header, and not parse your data. You will need to do some pre-processing before giving your data to zenity :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
menu=("option1" "option2" "option3")
desc=("description1" "description2" "description3")

# this for loop will create a new array ("option1" "description1" "option2" ...)
# there will be issues if the 2 arrays don't have the same length    
for (( i=0; i<${#menu[*]}; ++i)); do
    data+=( "${menu[$i]}" "${desc[$i]}" )
done

ans=$(zenity --list --column=Menu --column=Description --height 170 "${data[@]}")
```

Comment: If I were to update the description array would I need to then remake the data array to reflect that? Should i just update the data array directly?

Comment: @Kulpas you can add new values at the end of the array by doing `data+=( "option4" "description4" )`. If you want to edit an existing value, you'll need to know its position in the array. Then, you can just do `data[1]="newDescription1"` (arrays in bash start with a 0 position)